# Assemblyinfo.cs is not generated correctly ,Newline in constant, errors

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

Every time I create a new project for WPF a n AssemblyInfo.cs is generated, but there are several "CS1010 Newline in constant" Errors.
I have to go to the file and edit them manually every time. I would like to fix this permanently, but I cannot find any info on how where the data is pulled from to generate the file.

The parts of the file that give me the error are the same two:

```
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("
            ")]
```

AND

```
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © 
             2023")]
```

This is the way they show. I single line them manually for now...

Comment: Did u try repair or reinstall Visual Studio? The AssemblyInfo.cs file is typically generated by Visual Studio based on the project properties, and it should be automatically formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

AssemblyInfo.cs file: Property file containing program version, information, and copyright.
The AssemblyCompany and AssemblyCopyright you mentioned in the above file are generated by Visual Studio by reading computer information, so we need to consider this issue from two aspects.

**1. Issues with the computer itself.**

Go to the registry to view relevant information.

32 system:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion

64-bit systems:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion

Find and modify the values of RegisteredOrganization and RegisteredOwner in CurrentVersion (you can modify them to the values you want, try not to include special symbols or make them empty).

[image]

**2. Visual Studio issue.**

Please try to use the Visual Studio installation tool to fix it here. If it still doesn't work, you can try reinstalling Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I see thise fields are already populated correctly , but not read correctly by VS.
I have tried to use net 7.0 when creating  more projects and that seems to have bypassed the issue.
Our Site support is now looking into why VS do not read those values correctly.

Comment: @FilippoSantarelli Using .net 7.0 has better compatibility with win10 and win11. Very glad you were able to resolve this issue